# How to make lambda do one db call instead of severals

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Is this example bad practice because it make several database calls?

Is it any way I can make this to one DB call? Like use 'where' instead of 'firstOrDefault' and compare FlagDate with each date on the message in my messageList?

```
foreach (var message in messageList)
{
    var dayFlag = db.DayFlags.FirstOrDefault(x => 
                                    x.FlagDate == message.MessageDate);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to retrieve only the dayFlags which a corresponding Date to the messageList, you need to extract the dates first in a separate list, then pass it to a Linq To Sql query.

Note that to retrieve only the first DayFlags of each Date, you need to group the flags by date.

```
var dates = messageList.Select(m => m.MessageDate).ToList();
var dayFlags = db.DayFlags.GroupBy(flag => flag.FlagDate)
                          .Where(group => dates.Contains(group.Key))
                          .Select(group => group.First());
```

Comment: Thanx! That made it! There was only one error beacause you missed one bracket at the end of (group.Key). .Where(group => dates.Contains(group.Key)) <---

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with linq:

```
var dates = messageList.Select(m => m.MessageDate).ToList();
var dayFlags = from df in db.DayFlags
               where dates.Contains(df.FlagDate)
               select df;
```